# bootstrap for jade thumbnail li elements

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

So my problem is that when attempting to use the `li` element along with the span2-4 classes jade does not register them and the `li` element does not have the correct sizing. I'm doing this along with express btw. Is the span class depreciated now? Is there another way to size my thumbnails to put them in a grid?

```
block content
div.container
 h1(align="center") Motivation
  br
  div(align="center",id="motivation_pic")
   ul.thumbnails
    li.span3
     a(href="#").thumbnail
      img(src="../img/NuclearArms.jpg",alt="", style="width:200px; height:250px;")
    li.span3 
     a(href="#").thumbnail 
      img(data-src="holder.js/300x200",alt="")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of twitter bootstrap, then the grid system was changed:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid